Writing an EF on a SCOSTA card
I new to programming with smart cards and I have in hand a blank SCOSTA card and an ACR39 Smart card reader. As far as I read, SCOSTA cards are compatible with ISO7816-4, -8 and -9 standards. Its specification can be found here.I just want to do a simple procedure, write an EF with content "Name:Noor" and read it back. What is the correct sequence of commands to achieve this?
I have another problem, while trying to write some stuffs on the card, I think I messed up something. Now, every time, the APDU (00 A4 00 00 02 3F 00) for selecting the MF is returning 6D 00 : Instruction code not supported or invalid.. How can I reset the card and erase all data on it?
